# Delay execution 1 second

Tags: c++, delay, sleep

So I am trying to program a simple tick-based game. I write in C++ on a linux machine. The code below illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
{
    functioncall();
    sleep(1000); // wait 1 second for the next function call
}
```

Well, this doesn't work. It seems that it sleeps for 40 seconds, then prints out whatever the result is from the function call.

I also tried creating a new function called delay, and it looked like this:

```
void delay(int seconds)
{
    time_t start, current;

    time(&start);

    do
    {
        time(&current);
    }
    while ((current - start) < seconds);
}
```

Same result here. Anybody?

Comment: Let me guess, you're printing something in functioncall(), but are not flushing?

Comment: What is the purpose of functioncall()? Does it do some kind of output which may not have been flushed?

Comment: You could try replacing '\n' with std::endl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reiterate on what has already been stated by others with a concrete example:

Assuming you're using `std::cout` for output, you should call `std::cout.flush();` right before the sleep command. See [this MS knowledgebase article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94227)

Answer (score 4):

sleep(n) waits for n seconds, not n microseconds.
Also, as mentioned by Bart, if you're writing to stdout, you should flush the stream after each write - otherwise, you won't see anything until the buffer is flushed.

Comment: AFAIK not in a portable way - see @Rohit's answer for OS-dependent approaches to this.

Answer (score 2):

> So I am trying to program a simple tick-based game. I write in C++ on a linux machine.

if `functioncall()` may take a considerable time then your ticks won't be equal if you sleep the same amount of time.

You might be trying to do this:

```
while 1: // mainloop
   functioncall()
   tick() # wait for the next tick
```

Here `tick()` sleeps approximately `delay - time_it_takes_for(functioncall)` i.e., the longer `functioncall()` takes the less time `tick()` sleeps.

`sleep()` sleeps an integer number of seconds. You might need a finer time resolution. You could use [`clock_nanosleep()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_nanosleep.2.html) for that.

#### Example Clock::tick() implementation

```
// $ g++ *.cpp -lrt && time ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>        // perror()
#include <stdlib.h>        // ldiv()
#include <time.h>        // clock_nanosleep()

namespace {
  class Clock {
    const long delay_nanoseconds;
    bool running;
    struct timespec time;
    const clockid_t clock_id;

  public:
    explicit Clock(unsigned fps) :  // specify frames per second
      delay_nanoseconds(1e9/fps), running(false), time(),
      clock_id(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) {}

    void tick() {
      if (clock_nanosleep(clock_id, TIMER_ABSTIME, nexttick(), 0)) {
        // interrupted by a signal handler or an error
        perror("clock_nanosleep");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  private:
    struct timespec* nexttick() {
      if (not running) { // initialize `time`
        running = true;
        if (clock_gettime(clock_id, &time)) {
          //process errors
          perror("clock_gettime");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      }
      // increment `time`
      // time += delay_nanoseconds
      ldiv_t q = ldiv(time.tv_nsec + delay_nanoseconds, 1000000000);
      time.tv_sec  += q.quot;
      time.tv_nsec = q.rem;
      return &time;
    }
  };
}

int main() {
  Clock clock(20);
  char arrows[] = "\\|/-";
  for (int nframe = 0; nframe < 100; ++nframe) { // mainloop
    // process a single frame
    std::cout << arrows[nframe % (sizeof(arrows)-1)] << '\r' << std::flush;
    clock.tick(); // wait for the next tick
  }
}
```

Note: I've used `std::flush()` to update the output immediately.

If you run the program it should take about 5 seconds (100 frames, 20 frames per second).

Answer (score 0):

I guess on linux u have to use `usleep()` and it must be found in `ctime`

And in windows you can use delay(), sleep(), msleep()